# How to make the java Mail class authenticate me in a mail in two steps

Tags: java, email, two-factor-authentication

When I enter Gmail, it redirects me to an external page where I have to put a password and email, right after to a gmail login window where I have to enter the credentials.Adding the properties described in the code I can't get it to work.

The error is this:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS; nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
PKIX path validation failed: 
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: 
Usage constraint TLSServer check failed:
```

The code:

````
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String username = "username@gmail.com";
        final String password = "password";

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); //TLS

        Session session = Session.getInstance(prop,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(
                    Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("to_username_a@gmail.com, to_username_b@yahoo.com")
            );
            message.setSubject("Testing Gmail TLS");
            message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                    + "\n\n Please do not spam my email!");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PKIX path validation failed:  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:

You probably are missing some sort of TLS connection properties that you need to test.

Means either of the following:

- The Gmail server is requiring that you have a Cert when doing a TLS connection
- You are using a cert but it is not what gmail is looking for.
- You are using a cert, gmail likes it but it is expired.

If you go to firefox, and go to [www.gmail.com](http://www.gmail.com), you will see it is https:// connection, and if you click on the (Key Lock) beside the URL in firefox, you can look for more information about the Certificate details.

There is a whole page about how to use the gmail API using Java

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java